# R STAN - How to formulate multivariate co-variance matrix

Tags: r, bayesian, stan

I am currently using R stan to fit a multivariate normal distribution. The current model is

b ~ MVN ( 0 , Sigma )

where

b  = ( x1 , x2 , x3 )
0  = ( 0 , 0 ,0 )

Sigma =
[image]

I am able to build the co-variance matrix using the following:

```
parameters {
    row_vector b[3];    
    real<lower=0> b_sigma[3];
    real<lower=-1, upper=1> b_rho[3];
}

transformed parameters {
    matrix[3,3] b_SIGMA;

    b_SIGMA[1,1] = b_sigma[1] ^ 2;
    b_SIGMA[2,2] = b_sigma[2] ^ 2;
    b_SIGMA[3,3] = b_sigma[3] ^ 2;

    b_SIGMA[1,2] = b_rho[1] * b_sigma[1] * b_sigma[2] ;
    b_SIGMA[2,1] = b_rho[1] * b_sigma[1] * b_sigma[2] ;

    b_SIGMA[3,1] = b_rho[2] * b_sigma[1] * b_sigma[3];
    b_SIGMA[1,3] = b_rho[2] * b_sigma[1] * b_sigma[3];

    b_SIGMA[2,3] = b_rho[3] * b_sigma[2] * b_sigma[3];
    b_SIGMA[3,2] = b_rho[3] * b_sigma[2] * b_sigma[3];
}
```

However this to me seems incredibly manual and inefficient. Is there a proper or recommended way for building such variance structures ?

On a highly related note [PROC MIXED in SAS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect019.htm) offers a wide array of "out the box" variance structures such as unstructured, compound symmetry, autoregressive , etc. Is there an equivalent in STAN or will I need to manually construct them each time ?

NOTE:  As this question was more theoretical I assumed that data + a fully working example was not beneficial. I am happy to provide data + fully working example though if people would like to play around with it or deem otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction isn't guaranteed to produce a positive definite matrix. There's a `cov_matrix` type and a `cholesky_cov_matrix` type that will guarantee positive definiteness. The latter goes with the`multi_normal_cholesky` parameterization.  We usually recommend scaling a correlation matrix, for which there are parallel types.

There aren't any out of the box variance structures in Stan.  But there are several within RStanArm, which may be more what you're looking for.  It is a higher-level language than Stan itself and lets you specify autoregressive and soon spatial models as well as various hierarchical structure. And it automatically preconditions with a QR decomposition.